# How to make same hover style for both item and the link inside it?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a menu which is based on list (`ul`) with left float.  So there will be a link in each `li`.  but in the hover of the `li` the link turns to transparent color and each `li` has a specific id with a background image.

I made half of it, but there is a big different between the link hover and the `li` `hover`.
Check out my code here:
http://jsfiddle.net/mhhbs/

This is an image of what I mean by hover image.

[image]

Here is my code anyway:

```css
#nav {
    font: 30px 'LeagueGothicRegular', Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #f9f8cc;
    width:450px;
    clear: both;
    height: 56px;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 50px;
    background:#c2c2c2;
}

#nav ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#nav li {
    list-style-type: none;
    background-image: transparent;
    color: #FDE99D;
    float: left;
    height:50px; width:100px;
    border-right:1px #900 solid;
    text-align:center;

}

#nav li a {
    /**padding:10px 20px 10px 16px;**/
    color: #000;
    text-shadow: 0px 2px 2px #222;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

#nav li a:hover {
    color: #999;
    color:transparent !important;
    text-shadow: none;
}

#nav li:hover {
    background:url(http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/duesseldorf/32/home.png) red; 
    background-size: 83px 56px; 
    color: #999;
    color:transparent !important;
    text-shadow: none;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Replace

```
#nav li a:hover {
```

with

```
#nav li:hover a {
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mhhbs/1/

This way both styles are based on hover of the `li`.

Comment: I also suggest adding `display:block;width:100%;height:100%;` to your hrefs in order to make them fill the lis. http://jsfiddle.net/mhhbs/2/